# Only display the fontawesome icon in button

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I have this button with a `fa` icon.

```html
<p-button><i class="fa fa-thumb-tack" [ngClass]="{'active': pinned}"></i></p-button>
```

Currently it looks like this [image]

Is there anyway that I can just display the icon and not the button (making the icon clickable basically).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to customize your `p-button` style, like making its background opacity as 0.

Or you can just display only the icon and bind event to it:

```html
<i class="fa fa-thumb-tack" [ngClass]="{'active': pinned}" (click)="something()"></i>
```

However you have to make it by yourself, since PrimseNG doesn't support that kind of icon button.

Answer (score 0):

The  apparently has a yellow background set. You can try:

```
<p-button style='background-color: transparent; border: none'>
    <i style='color:silver' class="fa fa-thumb-tack" [ngClass]="{'active': pinned}"></i>
</p-button>
```

You can set the icons color to one that makes it more visible against the whitish background.

Comment: @user545871 Why use <p-button> instead of <button> . Also try this with or without <button> tag. [class.active]="pinned" . If 'pinned' is true, active class will add to class list